# UILabel not displaying multiple lines

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, uilabel

I know this is a very common issue here on stack overflow, however, i haven't been able to figure out what is going on by looking at the various threads on the topic.

I've got a nib file with a UITableViewCell subclass and a UILabel in the cell. The desired behavior is for the UILabel to expand vertically and display multiple lines of text (if the text is long enough). I've set the number of lines property in interface builder to 0, and I've also set the line breaks to word wrap (also in interface builder). When I display the cell, I am setting the height of the cell to be a function of sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: linebreakmode: using the text of the cell. The height is returning correctly for the cell, however the UILabel does not wrap, nor does it expand vertically.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE

Here is the code I used to calculate the height of the cell:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForCellGiveText:(NSString *)text
{
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[self defaultMainFont] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return size.height + (2 * VERT_PADDING) + INTER_LABEL_PADDING;
}
```

I was hoping to let interface builder automatically handle everything having to do with actually resizing the label (and not the cell)

Comment: Could you post some code of how you calculate the corresponding height and set it? Otherwise it's hard to find out if you made a serious error. Have you tried to use `sizeToFit` and if this has any effect?

Comment: ya I tried to add that programatically in cellForRowAtIndexPath: to no avail. Also tried adding it in initWithCoder: for the cell itself.

Comment: You set the cells height in heightRorRowAtIndexPath:. Whatever height you set in cellForRowAtIndexPath is ignored.

Comment: Where are you calling `heightForCellGiveText`?

Comment: I'm confused... `UILabel`s don't do multi-lined text... Did you mean to say `UITextView`?

Comment: + (CGFloat)heightForCellGiveText:(NSString *)text is called by heightForRowAtIndexPath. It sets the height of the cell (making sure the cell is large enough to display the entire label). it has no effect on the label itself.